# Pods not connecting with service having same labels -Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, label, kubernetes-service

I create one pod with `label:appenv` and one service of type node port with a selector as `appenv`. But when I use `kubectl get ep service-name` it's showing "no endpoints"(means service is not connecting with that pod).

Here  are my `pod.yaml` and `service.yaml`

`pod.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: pod1
  labels:
    app: appenv
spec:
  containers:
  - name: app
    image: aathith/lbt:v1
    ports:
    - name: app-port
      containerPort: 8082
  restartPolicy: Never
```

`service.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app
spec:
  selector:
    app: appenv
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8082
    targetPort: 8082
    nodePort: 30082
    protocol: TCP
```

output for `kubectl get po --show-labels`
[image]

output for `kubectl get svc`[image]

output for `kubectl get svc app`

[image]

1. Why am I not able to connect my pod to this service?
2. How can I change the above files to connect with each other?

Comment: can you provide output of commands: "kubectl get pod --show-labels", "kubectl get svc" and "kubectl get svc app".

Comment: @VasilyAngapov updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pod is in "Completed" state - that is the problem. It is not in state "Running". Why? Because command in container was finished with 0 exit code. In normal situation container's running command should not exit unless it's a Job or Cronjob. You see what I mean?

Comment: Is there anyway to  expose a completed pod?? @vasily

Comment: Nope, because it is not running. It is finished. How will you expose something which is not running anymore?

Comment: but that pod is not supposed to be in a completed state. how can I keep the pod in running state until I manually stop it?? @vasily

Comment: I cannot answer you because the answer will be too big. Please learn more about Docker containers and how to run them.

Comment: You need to make sure you app pod is doing what you expect it to. FOr the pod to stay running, it's main process must not exit. Double check your CMD or ENTRYPOINT in the dockerfile, or you can override these in the pod manifest.